# Cloud sync storage to sync millions of files 1TB for personal use on average laptop

Tags: file-synchronization, cloud-storage

I'm looking for a cloud storage solution that can sync 1TB of data just for personal use, no business or anything but consists of millions of files on an average laptop. I would like a good web interface to view photos or videos synced or share files to others, sometimes publicly like on Facebook so they can see them. I don't care about collaboration folders or collaboration features, just my little copy online that I can let others in as I deem necessary to some files or to go though photo memory lane in my web browser or randomly view files online instead of on my computer.

For reference my laptop is a mac and has 8GB of memory and 2.6GHZ processor.

- Dropbox didn't workout because everything was just amazing until I went past their hidden half-undocumented 300,000 file soft limit after which the client stalled out and my files were trapped on their servers with no way off for about 5-ish years until I found some cheap and crummy service to pull them off AT LAST! Dropbox also keeps in-memory tabs on every file which ate up all of my computer memory
- Google Drive is nearly just as bad, it also eats up a tremendous amount fo RAM, going on 3GB so far, and like Dropbox seems to stall a bit quite often, randomly restart the sync engine pretty often especially when file count gets up to about 200,000, plus give very nagging and annoying popups all the time about how it can't convert this image (I don't care) or had trouble uploading this arbitrary file (again I don't care and can manually upload it if it's that important but rarely is) furthermore Google Drive locks to a computer so if I format this computer which I did at one time and then re-install it and place all the files back it has to backup to a whole different folder from scratch making me delete it's progress from the previous format. Too many issues with it and between all the restarts and rescans of the software and the mass slowing down of my computer I don't think it'll ever actually finish.

I'm at loss as to what to do, every suggestion website I looked at praised Dropbox and such but I'm never ever in my life touching that crap again, I tried for months for abotu 5 years to get my files off and every answer pointed to one solution "Use the client" - With Google Sync client also beginning to fail as a viable option any help would be great. I've seen other suggestions but I've put money into both services and don't have a lot of money to keep placing into a dozen other solutions.

EDIT:
Not interested in self hosting or anything, don't really have any hard drives around here nor want to lug hard drives around also don't want to deal with server setup and maintenance - I mean I could do that but it would just end up being overly complicated and likely too expensive especially for bandwidth and all over time.  Looking to spend around $15 or less for 1TB of cloud storage online with cloud sync functionality that's accessible from any platform even mobile phones.

If nothings really out there like this I might just stick with Google Drive, it's at least better than Dropbox and a bit more doable if I want to work outside the client but welcome any suggestions if there are any.

Comment: well, the software which comes in my mind is [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/), although i haven't tested it myself for such a usecase... but it is used in big [scaled fields](https://nextcloud.com/globalscale/) like global companies or governmental services. - you can [look for a provider](https://nextcloud.com/providers/) which fits your bill, or [install it on your own webspace](https://nextcloud.com/install/) and maybe [integrate external storages](https://nextcloud.com/files/#storage) if you run out of space... ;-)

Comment: Nextcloud was my first thought as well, but as you don't care about the collaboration features you might rather wish to take a look at [Seafile](https://www.seafile.com/). I'm not using it myself, hence I cannot say how it meets *all* your requirements. Seafile [has partners](https://www.seafile.com/en/partner/), some of them also offer hosted Seafile instances.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy edited my question to further add some details I forgot to add

Comment: @June Thanks for the update. I've updated my previous comment as well with [a link to Seafile partners](https://www.seafile.com/en/partner/) offering hosted instances and more.

Comment: @June as already mentioned in my first comment, you CAN host it yourself, but you MUSTN'T! - so in your case have a look at the [nextcloud service-providers](https://nextcloud.com/providers/) to find one which fits your requirements regarding costs/space. **||** and also the [external storage](https://nextcloud.com/files/#storage) may still be valid for this use-case (if provided), as it is hardly meant for spare hard drives but rather other (maybe cheaper) online-storages (NFS, FTP, WebDAV, Amazon,...) as backend.

Comment: and to additional mention it: Nextcloud is accessible from every platform at least with its web-GUI, but also has native sync-clients for [windows, mac & linux](https://nextcloud.com/install/#install-clients) and apps (which are not so good for syncing) for [android, ios & windows mobile](https://nextcloud.com/install/#tab-mobile). - but anyhow you can also sync your files with EVERY WebDAV-client!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy Thanks for the information. I did have a look at Nextcloud earlier and while Seafile really suits me better (although no providers for it) Nextcloud did come close 2nd. The external feature is intriguing but do you have to have a provider if using external? All the providers for Nextcloud are quite expensive, only about 2 have 1TB of storage but the price is immensely high on both (Many hundreds of dollars). I'd still hate to get a smaller storage from the same provider to use external storage because then I'm paying for 2 services. So if I use external is a provider needed?

Comment: Mega pro is $35/m for 2TB of storage. It is rather feature rich but not sure if it's UI is responsive....it was a little clunky last time I used it.

Comment: @June well... for sure you need at least one nextcloud-instance (with the *external storage* app enabled!) to manage the storages and also sharing, web-GUI, etc. - but be warned: performance may drop because of and depending on the external storage!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are going about this the wrong way and you should not be running an instant sync client if that is using a lot of memory.

If you use a product like AJC Sync instead you can then choose to do a regular sync be between your laptop and your choice of web storage like Dropbox or Onedrive or even a mixture of them.  AJC Sync only builds a sync plan showing what needs to be synced when you choose to so its not using memory all of the time and you are in more control of what is synced and can see what has changed.  In one project you can also sync to multiple cloud locations.

When creating the sync plan it only uses memory to build up the list of files that have changed so that is not likely to be too many each time.  It would not cope with a million files to sync at the same time but it would not have to because your initial sync you could break into smaller chunks but after that it would only have to cope with files changed.

I am the author of AJC Sync, read more here:
www.ajcsoft.com/file-sync.htm

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. **Going with a self hosting** (but you said you don't want)**:** In this case your hsting is probalby using cPanel and in there you can find [Softacoulous](https://www.softaculous.com/apps/files) and in there applications like OwnCloud or Pydio.
2. **Use File Sync providers:** you said you already tried Dropbox and GoogleDrive and you are not impressed. Try [Mega.io](https://mega.io/), that could be your solution.

Let me know if this helped.